# Facebook Graph API not returning null for cover photo

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to pick users' cover photo for use in an Android app. I have not taken any additional approvals from Facebook other than the open-public profile access.

Here is the code I am using right now, please tell me where I am going wrong. Currently, it is returning a null value.

```
String URL = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + THE_USER_ID + "?fields=cover&access_token=" + Utility.mFacebook.getAccessToken();

String finalCoverPhoto;

try {

    HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(URL);
    HttpResponse rp = hc.execute(get);

    if (rp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        String result = EntityUtils.toString(rp.getEntity());

        JSONObject JODetails = new JSONObject(result);

        if (JODetails.has("cover")) {
            String getInitialCover = JODetails.getString("cover");

            if (getInitialCover.equals("null")) {
                finalCoverPhoto = null;
        } else {
            JSONObject JOCover = JODetails.optJSONObject("cover");

            if (JOCover.has("source"))  {
                finalCoverPhoto = JOCover.getString("source");
            } else {
                finalCoverPhoto = null;
            }
        }
    } else {
        finalCoverPhoto = null;
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code which i have used for fetching Cover Photo.

Use `GraphRequest` instead of `DefaultHttpClient`.

```
 Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("fields", "cover");
            new GraphRequest(token,
                    "me",
                    params,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                            if (response != null) {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject();

                                    if (data.has("cover")) {
                                       String coverPicUrl = data.getJSONObject("cover").getString("source");
                                    }

                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }).executeAsync();
```

Check if your are getting value of `coverPicUrl`.

I hope it helps!